# Using sed command to replace index-version = "inmem" to index-version = "tsi1" in /etc./influxdb/influxdb.conf file

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I am trying to replace index-version = "inmem" to index-version = "tsi1" in /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf file

My command looks like this: `sed -i 's/index-version = "inmem"/index-version = "tsi1"/ /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf' and i am getting the error sed: -e expression #1, char 51: unknown option to`s'

Answer (score 1):

okie i found the error, the command should be

sed -i 's/index-version = "inmem"/index-version = "tsi1"/' /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf